# How to overcome the CSS/JS full-width background-color "flicker"

Tags: wordpress

So this is an "issue" that I've been experiencing for a new website that I've been building.

It utilizes WP Bakery's Visual Composer `Row` widget, and occurs when the CSS/JS kicks in to expand the header row from `default` to `stretch`. 
Because the header row has a background colour, the initial header looks like [this](https://snag.gy/LOPlX6.jpg). However, when the CSS/JS kicks in to expand the row, it then "flickers" and looks like [this](https://snag.gy/aNoskm.jpg).

This obviously looks very unprofessional, and was wondering can suggest anything that I could try.

Would appreciate any assistance.

Thanks!

Comment: You're asking us to help you with a JS/CSS issue without actually sharing code. None of us here -unfortunately- have the gift of Clairvoyance so you'll need to show us some code or a live example or we won't be able to help you out. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to other [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content)s (Flash of Unstyled Content). You have a few options.

One is to add the `stretch` attributes to the element in question specifically. Basically take: `.stretch { width: 100%; margin: 0 auto /* … whatever */ }` and apply those styles to your element, ideally by ID: `#my-header { width: 100%; margin: 0 auto /* … whatever */ }` and put them in your header so they're loaded right away, perhaps in your Customizer.

Another option is to find another way to add the `stretch` class to that element manually. I'm not familiar enough with VC to give examples (though, to be honest the few sites I've made that use it haven't seemed to have this issue?). The benefit of this would be that you don't need to duplicate CSS attributes, and don't need to wait to JS to apply the class, which probably isn't happening until the entire footer is loaded.

Another option is the all-too common (and arguably unnecessary/annoying) "full page loader". This is the option I'd avoid if I were you, but you can plop in a full screen white page with your logo and a spinner that goes away when the entire markup is loaded or when all resources are fetched. This delays users accessing your site, and most users would prefer to see a FOUC than a loading screen, based on my limited testing.

Answer (score 0):

I found three unsatisfactory answers to your question.

First, I'll explain, why does this problem happen, and when is it more difficult to fully fix.

Issue happens, as the WP Bakery Plugin composes the width and the centering done via, for example: left: 123px, using JS and  possibly also PHP (!!), which may do so, only on page upload completion stage.

The problem is much more difficult to solve, when the stretch row (or element) is coming after (below on the screen) a narrow usage of the center of the screen and possibly also a css 'clearfix' call.

**Partial Solution (1)**

Then, you may easily get the correct width, by passing it from the top element, using a css VAR (yes, css supports that...), **however** would have that correct width element start not at the left side of the screen.

Also, fixing it, using 'position: fix; left: 0' won't help, as then the next element below it, would cover it.

**Note:** it's Not the straight-forward thought of 100% Nor 100vw.. as you may have to take into account the reduction of the 17px scrolling element).

So.. this could be a solution if the Plugin team reads it, removes the JS solution, and generate the effect using css, which IMHO should be possible.

The beginning of code for such a soliton would look something like this:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    body{
     /* Define the CSS variable with the desired parent width */
     --parent-width: calc(100vw - 17px)!important;
     width: var(--parent-width);
    }

    .vc_section[data-vc-full-width-init],
    .vc_section[data-vc-full-width],
    .vc_row[data-vc-full-width],
    .vc_row[data-vc-full-width] div {
        /* Access the CSS variable on the child element, would be done with: */ 
        width: var(--parent-width)!important;
        /*A second option for 'width' not using the VAR*/
        width: calc(var(--parent-width) + 17px)!important;
        box-sizing: border-box!imporant;
    }

    .vc_row[data-vc-full-width]{    
      position: fixed!important;
      left: 0!important;
      margin-left: 0!important;
      padding-left: calc((1030px - (100vw - 17px) - 30px)/2)!important;
      padding-right: auto!important;    
      margin-right: 0!important;
      min-height: 100%!important
      }
}
```

**Note:**
The special css trick of using '**--parent-width:**' which enables passing a VAR value between various website elements.

Ok... time for second possible solution

**Partial Solution (2)**
This solution, just makes those flickering elements, take their place, however have 'opacity: 0', until there correct location and width is calculated by the Plugin's JS, and them 'brings them to light', by using a short JS for changing opacity to '1'

Possible **CSS** would look like this:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    body:not(.home) .vc_row-has-fill,
    body:not(.home) .vc_section[data-vc-full-width-init],
    body:not(.home) .vc_section[data-vc-full-width],
    body:not(.home) div.vc_row[data-vc-full-width] {
        opacity: 0!important;}

    body:not(.home) .vc_row-has-fill.row_loaded,
    body:not(.home) .vc_section[data-vc-full-width-init].row_loaded,
    body:not(.home) .vc_section[data-vc-full-width].row_loaded,
    body:not(.home) div.vc_row[data-vc-full-width].row_loaded { 
        opacity: 1!important; }
    }
```

**Note:**
The above css provides the 'opacity: 1' for the css class 'row_loaded' which does NOT exist on the HTML page when it uploads, however would have it's effect, once page is fully uploaded, as the below JS would add that class, thus triggering the 'opacity: 1' (which makes the element viable).

And the **JS** element like this:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  // Code to be executed when the window is fully loaded
    jQuery('body:not(.home) div.vc_row-has-fill,body:not(.home) .vc_section[data-vc-full-width-init],body:not(.home) .vc_section[data-vc-full-width],body:not(.home) .vc_row[data-vc-full-width]').addClass('row_loaded');
    console.log('Window is fully loaded!');
});
```

**Notes:**

1. I was not having this effect on the homapge, as this page has a more complex structure, thus the 'body:not(.home)' selecting.
2. I do Not have full width problem on narrow screens, where website uses the full screen, but I do have it on wide screen views, where screen usage is narrow in the center, and then comes a full width row with an image in the center and a background color.
3. To those of you asking to understand the root cause, you may have a look at the PHP file appending addiotnal classes and wraps to HTML elements, that are configured via the plugin to be 'full-width', for example as in plugin's file, as:

/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/include/templates/shortcodes/vc_section.php   line:67

```
if ( ! empty( $full_width ) ) {
    $wrapper_attributes[] = 'data-vc-full-width="true"';
    $wrapper_attributes[] = 'data-vc-full-width-init="false"';
    if ( 'stretch_row_content' === $full_width ) {
        $wrapper_attributes[] = 'data-vc-stretch-content="true"';
    }
    $after_output .= '<div class="vc_row-full-width vc_clearfix"></div>';
}
```

And, also additional files, as:
/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/include/templates/shortcodes/vc_row.php    line:78
/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/js/dist/js_composer_front.min.js  line:10
/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/js/frontend_editor/shortcodes/containers/vc_section.js  line:8

That means, there is an iterative process, that starts when the Plugin is called and identifies, a full-width indication. That process includes, adding 'wraps', HTML classes, performing calculations, and setting new values for some of the element and newly created 'wrapping' elements. That process takes those 'milliseconds' adding up to that about 1 second or so, which is the one, which is the main responsible for the flickering.

4. Possibly.. flickering is also influenced, by HTML css 'animation' where on the plugin, one may find 0.5s (seconds) transition time, for animation, which possibly might be used in regards to full-width. This requires additional 'investigation'.

**Partial Solution (3)**

IT seems like 'preloading' some Plugin files, makes the flickering shorter.

Those preload calls, are to be placed within relevant header.php file, as in:

```
<!-- Preload CSS files -->
<link rel="preload" href="/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/less/lib/controls.less" as="style">
<link rel="preload" href="/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/less/lib/frontend_editor_controls.less" as="style">
<link rel="preload" href="/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/less/lib/vc_mixins.less" as="style">
<link rel="preload" href="/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/less/shortcodes/vc_row.less" as="style">
<link rel="preload" href="/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/less/shortcodes/vc_section.less" as="style">
<link rel="preload" href="/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/less/shortcodes/vc_basic_grid/vc_grid.less" as="style">
<link rel="preload" href="/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/lib/bower/bootstrap3/less/navbar.less" as="style">

<!-- Preload JavaScript files -->
<link rel="preload" href="/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/js/dist/js_composer_front.min.js" as="script">
<link rel="preload" href="/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/js/dist/frontend-editor.min.js" as="script">
<link rel="preload" href="/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/js/frontend_editor/shortcodes/containers/vc_section.js" as="script">
```

**Possibly**
Possibly modifying the plugin *.less files containing the the CSS 'transition' property with 0.5s (seconds) to be 0 seconds, would also make the flickering shorter in time

/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/assets/css/js_composer.min.css line:7

For example:

```
.vc_row[data-vc-full-width]{transition:opacity .5s ease;overflow:hidden}
```